# How do I set my nginx perms to allow for multipart form submissions?

Tags: nginx, permissions, file-permissions, upload

I'm using Nginx with Puma (for a Rails application) on CentOS 7.  I'm confused about how to set up permissions for a file upload.  Currently when I try and upload a file (submit a multi-part form), I get the following error in nginx error log

```
2018/02/28 16:35:48 [crit] 31241#0: *148 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000006" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 96.92.233.165, server: example.com, request: "POST /people HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/people/new"
```

I'm trying to get everything to run as the "rails" user.  Below are my nginx and puma processes

```
[root@server /]# ps -elf | grep nginx
0 S root       944   920  0  80   0 -  2249 pipe_w 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
1 S root     31238     1  0  80   0 - 30712 rt_sig 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
5 S rails    31239 31238  0  80   0 - 30843 ep_pol 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S rails    31240 31238  0  80   0 - 30843 ep_pol 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S rails    31241 31238  0  80   0 - 30843 ep_pol 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
5 S rails    31242 31238  0  80   0 - 30843 ep_pol 15:06 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
[root@server /]# ps -elf | grep puma
1 S rails      582     1  0  80   0 - 135430 poll_s 16:19 ?       00:00:00 puma 3.11.2 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000,unix:///home/rails/scale_production/shared/sockets/puma.sock) [scale_production]
1 S rails      590   582  0  80   0 - 286725 futex_ 16:19 ?       00:00:02 puma: cluster worker 0: 582 [scale_production]
1 S rails      594   582  0  80   0 - 287282 futex_ 16:19 ?       00:00:03 puma: cluster worker 1: 582 [scale_production]
1 S rails      596   582  0  80   0 - 287255 futex_ 16:19 ?       00:00:02 puma: cluster worker 2: 582 [scale_production]
1 S rails      599   582  0  80   0 - 286939 futex_ 16:19 ?       00:00:02 puma: cluster worker 3: 582 [scale_production]
0 S root       946   920  0  80   0 -  2250 pipe_w 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

and below are the perms for the problematic directory.  What else should I be setting in order for this to work?

```
[root@server /]# ls -al /var/lib/nginx
total 12
drwx------  3  755 rails 4096 Feb 24 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Feb 24 14:33 ..
drwx------  7  755 rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 tmp
[root@server /]# ls -al /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body
total 8
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 .
drwx------ 7   755 rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 ..
[root@server /]# ls -al /var/lib/nginx/tmp
total 28
drwx------ 7   755 rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 .
drwx------ 3   755 rails 4096 Feb 24 14:33 ..
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 client_body
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 fastcgi
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 proxy
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 scgi
drwx------ 2 rails rails 4096 Feb 24 15:06 uwsgi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running nginx as the user named `rails` (which is unusual).

But one of your directories, `/var/lib/nginx/tmp`, is owned by the nonexistent user 755.

The usual reason this happens is mistakenly typing `chown` when you meant `chmod`.

You should be able to fix the problem by correcting the ownership of this directory.

```
chown rails /var/lib/nginx/tmp
```

BTW, you also seem to have disabled SELinux. You should [fix that](https://stopdisablingselinux.com/) at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: I just got this VPS from the A2 hosting company.  I didn't knowingly shut off anything.  Being a total noob I don't even know what "SELinux" is or why its good so I guess I'll have to look into that.

Comment: SELinux doesn't work on some low-end VPS providers. So that might be why it is not present.

Answer (score 2):

you can see `/var/lib/nginx/tmp` is owned by user 755. 
Probably you had used the wrong command: `chown` instead of `chmod`.

To fix this:

```
chmod 755 /var/lib/nginx/tmp
chown rails /var/lib/nginx/tmp
```